# UWP - Apply custom converter to value set by x:Uid directive

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have this simple **TextBlock** on my page:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="SettingsPage_StreamQualityTextBlock"
           Style="{StaticResource SectionTitleStyle}"/>
```

`Text` value is set from resource file by the `x:Uid` directive.

The thing is I want to apply a custom converter to the `Text` value of `TextBlock` through `StaticResource`, but when I do it like this

```
Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToUpperCase}}"
```

value is not set and converter is not applied.

Hence my question is:

**Is this somehow possible to do in XAML without programmatic modification of code behind part?**

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple attached property that monitors changes on the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`?

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static bool GetUseUpperCase(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseUpperCaseProperty);
    }
    public static void SetUseUpperCase(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(UseUpperCaseProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseUpperCaseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseUpperCase", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(false, (sender, args) =>
        {
            var textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
            textBlock.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(TextBlock.TextProperty, (s, e) =>
            {
                textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text.ToUpper();
            });
        }));
}
```

Then you just attach it to your `TextBlock` that needs to be capitalized.

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="SettingsPage_StreamQualityTextBlock"
           Style="{StaticResource SectionTitleStyle}"
           local:Helper.UseUpperCase="True" />
```

Comment: How does this not result in a StackOverflow? 
I'm trying it and I keep getting a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the value that you are passing to this textblock, am guessing data is in some sort of model or class. Identify the exact property name you are trying to bind and include it in the TextBinding declaration, like these

```
Text="{Binding [propertyName],Converter={StaticResource TextToUpperCase}}"
```

Replace property name above in boxed brackets with the property name you are binding to. Remember to remove the box-brackets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the issue, it's not in a model or class, it's just a label which text is bound to localized resource file and value itself is set by `x:Uid` directive.